# Не срабатывает preventDefault() при клике на ссылку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Вывел карточки постов в WordPress через ajax.

```
<a href="http://hitechbuld/2019/03" data-postid="132" rel="bookmark" class="thumb_3">
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="http://hitechbuld/wp-content/themes/hitechbud/img/no_image.jpg" alt="Отделочные работы 8">
  </div>
  <h4>Отделочные работы 8</h4>
  <p>Отделочные работы 8 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing ...</p>
</a>
```

Вот код который должен сработать при клике на карточку

```
$("#publication_content .thumb_3").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Но не срабатывает preventDefault() и идет перенаправление на страницу. Это связано с тем что эти карточки я добавлял через ajax? Как сделать так чтобы не было перенаправления и сработал preventDefault() ?

Comment: "Насоздавал ссылок, как теперь сделать чтобы они не работали как ссылки" - в чем же смысл и логика? Если тебе не нужно чтобы элемент работал как ссылка, то просто используй вместо `<a>` например `<span>` или `<div>` в качестве контейнера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Это связано с тем что эти карточки я добавлял через ajax?

Да. В момент выполнения кода навешивания обработчика события

```
$("#publication_content .thumb_3").click(function(e) {
```

элементов `.thumb_3` (а может и `#publication_content`) еще нет на странице, и выборка jQuery возвращает пустой набор элементов.

---

```
$("#publication_content").on("click", ".thumb_3", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

или

```
$(document).on("click", "#publication_content .thumb_3", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Сработал второй. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".thumb_3").click(function() {
    // гипотетический ajax запрос вернувший 'QWERTY'
    $("#publication_content").html('QWERTY');

    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="publication_content">
  <a href="http://hitechbuld/2019/03" data-postid="132" rel="bookmark" class="thumb_3">
    <div class="img-box">
      <img src="http://hitechbuld/wp-content/themes/hitechbud/img/no_image.jpg" alt="Отделочные работы 8">
    </div>
    <h4>Отделочные работы 8</h4>
    <p>Отделочные работы 8 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing ...</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы сработал вот такой вот код.                                                                    $("#publication_content .thumb_3").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        postContentId = $(this).attr('data-postid');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_order',
                name: postContentId
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#publication_content").html(response);
            }
        });
    });

Comment: То есть там ajax должен сработать после клика.

Comment: Это все делается на Wordpress

Comment: Всё как в ответе. Страница не перезагрузиться, return false отменяет действие элемента по-умолчанию.

Comment: Не работает.  Может это в вордпресе так?

Comment: Может этот селектор где-то дополнительно прослушивается?

Comment: Спасибо вам. Уже нашел ответ.